# Cannot update Ubuntu 20.10 for weeks?

Tags: package-management, updates, dependencies

I have three computers running Ubuntu 20.10, and none of them can update for a few weeks now.
They all report that "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" and that following package has unmet dependencies: grub-efi-amd64-signed:

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something has corrupted a Grub file, meaning Grub needs to be reinstalled. It's bizarre that the same issue would affect more than one machine, though, as the problem is not very common.

Try this from Terminal:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall grub
sudo apt install --reinstall grub2-common
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64-bin
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

Once this is done, do a `dist-upgrade`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

This should resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks. I never got the chance to try it, though - updating restarted itself (without me doing anything). I am confused - could it be on the server-side?